# How can I bracket match in a regex to correctly update C++ call sites?

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I'm trying to craft a one-liner to update a large body of C++ code. Let's say I
have call sites calling function `Foo` that accepts one argument, like so:

```
Foo(...);
```

Sometimes they're split across lines:

```
Foo(...,
    ...,
    ...);
```

I can't prove they don't also occur in other forms, like in a comma expression:

```
Foo(...), Blah();
```

I'd like to update all calls to `Foo` so that its sole argument is first passed
to another function `Bar`, then the result goes to `Foo`:

```
Foo(Bar(...));
```

I don't care about formatting, since I can use something like `clang-format` to
fix up the output; I just want correctness.

How can I do this with `perl` (or `sed` or anything else common) in a way that
is correct for an arbitrary argument expression, including ones that may
contain other function calls?

I know this is impossible using regular expressions in the formal language
sense. But perl regexes are not actually regular expressions, and I've seen
reference to bracket matching capabilities in perl regexes, but haven't found a
good explanation anywhere. Perhaps I'm mistaken.

Comment: where the string Bar comes from? post a sample large function along with expected output?

Comment: for the multiline `foo(...,` how is the output expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`perldoc` actually provides almost exactly this regexp in an example on [using the `(?R)` extended pattern](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3f_PARNO_)-(%3f-_PARNO_)-(%3f%2b_PARNO_)-(%3fR)-(%3f0)):

```
$re = qr{ (                   # paren group 1 (full function)
        foo
            (                 # paren group 2 (parens)
               \(
                     (        # paren group 3 (contents of parens)
                                (?:
                                  (?> [^()]+ ) # Non-parens without backtracking
                                |
                                  (?2)         # Recurse to start of paren group 2
                                )*
                                )
                          \)
                     )
                )
           }x;
```

So a one liner might look something like:

```
$ perl -i -0777 -pe 's/(Foo(\(((?:(?>[^()]+)|(?2))*)\)))/Foo(Bar($3))/;' my_file.cc
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed -n '/Foo(/,/)$/p' file`

This should get you the body of the function, then you can process it how you want.

So to inject a Bar() wrapper around the contents of Foo, you could do something like:

`sed -n '/Foo(/,/)$/{s/Foo(/Foo(Bar(/;s/)$/))/};p' file`

Update: if you need the semicolon on there

`sed -n '/Foo(/,/);$/{s/Foo(/Foo(Bar(/;s/);$/));/};p'`

Comment: This only works if the call to `Foo` extends to the end of the line, and is not embedded in a more complex expression, right? I admit I don't know `sed` well, so I might be wrong. But I think that's what the `$` is doing for you there.

Comment: It spans multiple lines, sed normally is thought of as a single line editor yet you can use it to process blocks of text, you just need to put an address range - in this case its a /regex/,/regex/ style range.